# I am getting a curly brace error but I do not understand why

Tags: java

I am getting the error java:35: error: illegal character: \29, all this should do is when a user clicks on the label it changes from "H" to "T"

I am also getting error: ';' expected
        }

and  error: reached end of file while parsing
        }

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


class Lab3Label extends JLabel{

    Lab3Label () {
        this.addActionListener(new FlipTheCoinListener());
    }



    public void FlipTheCoin(){
        int count = 0;
        if(count % 1 == 0 ){
            this.setText("H");
            count += 2;
        }
        else{
            this.setText("T");
            count -= 2;
        }
    }


}

        class FlipTheCoinListener implements ActionListener{


            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
             this.FlipTheCoin();
            }
    }
```

^ is the line in question

Comment: Yes, the error says that the final curly brace is an illegal character I am getting three errors should I add them to this?

Comment: Yes, please. I'm not getting the error mentioned when I put this into my NetBeans

Comment: I can't see why you would get an illegal character error but count%1 will always be 0.  you should be using count += 1 and count % 2, or even just using a boolean flag.

Comment: We are not allowed to use IDE's in class so I am doing this in textpad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a funny character on that line, as evidenced by the actual error you're getting, complaining about `\29`. It may be because you cut and pasted the code in from somewhere with the extraneous character.

If you really wanted to investigate properly, you could examine the hex contents of the file such as with (UNIXy systems):

```
od -xcb sourcefile.java
```

but it's probably easier just to delete the line totally and retype it.

Comment: That fixed it thanks now I am having an issue with the this.FlipTheCoin()

Comment: @user512915: that's a totally _different_ question. It should be submitted as a different question. But the bottom line is that your `this` doesn't have a `FlipTheCoin`. Your `this` is a listener which is _used_ by your label but does not have direct access to the label's methods.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you gave, it doesn't look like there's a 'curly-brace error'.

There are three main things you have to fix in your code:

1. Define `FlipTheCoinListener` as an [inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) inside `Lab3Label`.
2. The method `FlipTheCoin` is part of the outer class `Lab3Label`, look into how to call methods of an outer class, from an inner class.
3. The method `addActionListener` does not exist for [`JLabel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html),find the appropriate listener method you're supposed to use.

Comment: I changed label.FlipTheCoin() to this.FlipTheCoin()

Comment: We are not allowed to use IDE's in class our instructor makes us use TextPad

Answer (score 1):

This may be an error in the way you formatted your post but  you have a } before your import statements.